# WinPcapDevice is still listening after stopping the capture

Tags: c#, arp

For some research of network activity on my private network, I came across [NightHawk](https://github.com/klemenb/nighthawk). So after downloading and testing, I tried to print out some Tcp packets when "sniffing". This worked for me very fine.

But when clicking the "stop button", the sniff function pauses for around 3 seconds and resumes sniffing to the network and printing arriving packets.

After searching for the missing `-=` of a "sniffing to the network" event handler, I found one and fixed it. BUT the problem is still active.

So for some reason - I can't find out - the `OnPacketArrival` event is still "alive" AND called from somewhere, even though I stopped capturing AND removed the event handler.

Edit:
As requested, here is some code:

```
// start listening on a device (combobox index)
public void StartDevice(int deviceIndex)
{
    Started = true;

    DeviceInfo = DeviceInfoList[deviceIndex];
    Device = WinPcapDeviceList.Instance[deviceIndex];    

    Sniffer = new Sniffer(DeviceInfo);
    ARPTools = new ARPTools(DeviceInfo);
    NDTools = new NDTools(DeviceInfo);
    SSLStrip = new SSLStrip();
    Scanner = new Scanner(DeviceInfo);

    Sniffer.SnifferResult += new SnifferResultHandler(sniffer_OnSnifferResult);
    SSLStrip.SSLStripped += new SSLStripHandler(SSLStrip_OnSSLStripped);

    Scanner.ScannerResponse += new ScannerResponseReceived(scanner_OnResponse);
    Scanner.ScanComplete += new ScannerEventHandler(scanner_OnScanComplete);
    Scanner.HostnameResolved += new ScannerHostnameResolvedHandler(scanner_HostnameResolved);

    // open device, set filters & events, start capturing
    Device.Open(DeviceMode.Promiscuous, 1);
    Device.Filter = "(arp || ip || ip6)";

    Device.OnPacketArrival += device_OnPacketArrival; // Subscribe the event for arriving packets
    Device.StartCapture();
    }
// stop listening on a device
public void StopDevice()
{
    Started = false;

    if (Device == null) return;

    Device.StopCaptureTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200);
    Device.StopCapture();
    Device.OnPacketArrival -= device_OnPacketArrival; // This is to unsubscribe the event. This was coded by me
    Device.Close();
}
```

So has someone an explanation for this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you call, or does it have, any Dispose method? Some code might help here..

Comment: Maybe you have attached the event more than once?

Comment: Your problem sounds more like a missing `+=` event handler, i.e. the "Stop" buttons click event isn't registered.

Comment: @ChrisWatts: Device has no Dispose methode...

Comment: @Gusman: No. the event is only attached one time

Comment: @Filburt: Stop and Start sniffing button is the same. There is a check wether the sniffer is started or not. If (!Sniffer.Started) then the sniffer is started, else the sniffer is stopped.